# Voice dictation intermittently stops working for Catalina

Tags: catalina, voice-dictation

I have voice dication enabled (settings > keyboard > dictation) and set to activate with `Fn Fn`.

It works beautifully for a while, but then just stops.   A reboot appears to fix it.   But then it will stop working again.

When it stops working, pressing `Fn Fn` results in a longer ding than when it is working.   Also in the console app, I see this error:

```
error   06:42:40.620584-0700    corespeechd  PropertyID=1667788144 is NULL
```

Comment: Same problem for me on macOS Monterey.

Answer (score 1):

Having this same problem, with Ventura, and the previous OS too.   It works fine for a bit, than all of a sudden Fn Fn turns on the dictation box but no text is registered/entered and I have to restart for it to work again, for a little while until the cycle repeats.  Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/334478)