# Dictation stopped working macOS Monterey version 12

Tags: voice-dictation

On a new 2021 Macbook, with macOS Monterey 12.0, I used Dictation frequently.

A few days ago Dictation just stopped working completely. The microphone overlay pops up but there is not movement in response to sound and no words are generated.

I thought it might be a microphone input issue but checking the Sound settings, the microphone is selected and working great.

I have turned it on and off as suggested by [this question and answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243047/dictation-just-stopped-working). However doing the on off restart dance has not fixed the issue for me.

Also found this [AskDifferent question where Dictation stops working intermittently](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428179/voice-dictation-intermittently-stops-working-for-catalina). However for me restarting has not fixed the issue.

I opened the Console app and did see an error when I tried using Dictation. Don't know if that is helpful or not, I don't know what I am looking for.

How can I fix Dictation so it works again?

[image]